# Sort array of objects into Top N using lodash with n+1 as "others"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, lodash

Assuming I have this data structure, Example input :

```
[ {name: "a", val:1},
  {name: "b", val:2},
  {name: "c", val:3},
  {name: "d", val:4},
  {name: "e", val:5},
  {name: "f", val:1},
  {name: "g", val:2},
  {name: "h", val:1},
]
```

I want to output 2 arrays :

The first is the val attribute from the object, with the top (highest) values first and then the sum of the remaining elements. If we assume to take n=5, as being a top 5 result + "the rest". So this array on array[5] = the sum of all the val properties not in the top 5. Example output:

```
[2,3,4,5,2,3]
```

The second array would be the name property corresponding to the top 5, with array[5] = "others", or some other arbitrary string. Example output:

```
["b","c","d","e","g","others"]
```

How can this be achieved with maximum efficiency and/or maximum code clarity using lodash? [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)

**EDIT:** Example code :

```
       var n = 5;
  var input = [ 
      {name: "a", val:1},
      {name: "b", val:2},
      {name: "c", val:3},
      {name: "d", val:4},
      {name: "e", val:5},
      {name: "f", val:1},
      {name: "g", val:2},
      {name: "h", val:1},
    ];
    var sortedArray = _.sortByOrder(input, ['val'], [false]);
    var topNValues = _.pluck(_.slice(sortedArray, 0, n), 'val');
    var restValues = _.pluck(_.slice(sortedArray, n, sortedArray.length), 'val');
    var restAdded = _.reduce(restValues, function(i, j) {
    return i + j;
}, 0); 
    topNValues.splice(n, 0,restAdded);
    $scope.array1 = topNValues; 
    var names = _.pluck(_.slice(sortedArray, 0, n), 'name');
    names.splice(n,0,"others");
    $scope.array2 = names;
```

There must be a cleaner, chained way than my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u1w4da6r/2/

Comment: I'd recommend to go for maximum clarity first. Afaik, lodash has no [top `k` algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), and implementing one yourself can be complicated.

Comment: Please put the code you already have in your question, not only in a fiddle (which is good as an *additional* helper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's not a single chain, but it seems fairly easy to read. I haven't done any performance testing, but ease-of-understanding should probably be your primary goal.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Nqpwgq?editors=001)

```
function groupOthers (obj, n) {
  var indicesToKeep = _.chain(obj)
    .map(function (item, index) { //zip each item with its index
      return {item: item, index: index}
    })
    .sortBy(function (zipped) { //sort by the val (highest to lowest)
      return -zipped.item.val
    })
    .take(n) //take the top 5
    .map('index') // we only care about the indices
    .value()

  var partitioned = _.partition(obj, function (item, index) {
    return _.includes(indicesToKeep, index)
  })

  var finalObjJoined = partitioned[0].concat({
    name: 'others',
    val: _.sum(partitioned[1], 'val')
  })

  return [_.map(finalObjJoined, 'name'), _.map(finalObjJoined, 'val')]
}

console.log(groupOthers(x, 5))
```

Comment: Note that this works with the latest version of Lodash. It seems to fail with Lodash 3.5 for reasons that I don't feel like investigating :)