# Javascript function to get 3 objects based by props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to make function to get top3 objects from an array based by props. My site can't load up so i think this function runs endlessly but i cant figure out why.

```
renderItems = (items) => {
    let top3 = []
    let tempArr = items  
    let allNumbers = []
    while (top3.length < 3){
        allNumbers = []
        for(let i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++){
        allNumbers = [...allNumbers, tempArr[i].hearts] 
        }
        const result = tempArr.filter(i => i.hearts === Math.max(...allNumbers))
        top3 = [...top3, ...result]
        let countOfdeleted = 0
        for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            tempArr.splice(result[i].id-countOfdeleted, 1)
            countOfdeleted++
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++){
            tempArr[i].id = i
        } 
    } 
    console.log(top3);  
}
```

Comment: Seems like the Lodash javascript library would be useful here. No point re-inventing the wheel. Lodash (previously Underscore) is totally awesome. I think of it as being like SQL for object structures and arrays. I prefer the Underscore website for its examples

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting ***input*** and ***expected output*** using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please add the object you are reading

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623441/sort-array-of-objects-into-top-n-using-lodash-with-n1-as-others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the assumption that 'items' is an array of objects and that each object in 'items' will have at-least 2 props namely 'id' and 'hearts'.

Further, there is no clarity on the significance of 'countOfdeleted' and 'tempArr'. Hence, it is assumed

1. that one needs to know how many elements of the 'items' array were not included (in the top3) as 'countOfdeleted'
2. that the remaining objects need to have their 'id' updated (based on index)

With the aforementioned assumptions, the below should implement the required logic:

```js
const items = [
{ id: 0, hearts: 5 }, { id: 1, hearts: 4 }, { id: 2, hearts: 5 }, 
{ id: 3, hearts: 3 }, { id: 4, hearts: 5 }, { id: 5, hearts: 2 },
{ id: 6, hearts: 2 }, { id: 7, hearts: 1 }, { id: 8, hearts: 4 }
];

const getTop3 = (arr = items) => {
const maxVal = arr.reduce((fin, itm) => itm.hearts > fin ? itm.hearts : fin, 0);
const topAll = arr.filter(obj => obj.hearts === maxVal);
const sansTop3 = arr
.filter(obj => obj.hearts !== maxVal)
.map((obj, idx) => ({...obj, id: idx}));
console.log('countOfDeleted: ', arr.length - (topAll.length > 3 ? topAll.length : 3));
console.log('rest with updated-id (tempArr): ', sansTop3);
return topAll.length > 3 ? topAll.slice(0, 3) : [...topAll];
};

console.log('\ntop3:\n^^^^\n', getTop3());
```

**Approach / Explanation**

1. Find the 'maximum-value' (maxVal) based on the prop ('hearts')
2. Find all objects which have the props matching maxVal (stored in array 'topAll')
3. [Optional: Gather remaining 'items' elements and update their 'id' in 'sansTop3' array, to match the 'tempArr' in the question]
4. [Optional: Determine the number of 'items' deleted, to match countOfdeleted in the question]
5. If more than 3 elements have props ('heart') matching 'maxVal', return only 3; otherwise, return the all top-value element/s